# Nifi - Can not update a JSON column which is auto parse a JSON value into binary

Tags: apache-nifi, jsonparser

I'm trying to use Nifi to sync data between 2 databases, but when a table has a JSON column, it runs with an error message:

`2022-05-04 14:38:02,236 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL PutSQL[id=1cea62d7-358b-3071-1578-751f855f5bb4] Failed to update database due to a failed batch update, java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.. There were a total of 1 FlowFiles that failed, 0 that succeeded, and 0 that were not execute and will be routed to retry; : java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'. java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Cannot create a JSON value from a string with CHARACTER SET 'binary'.`

And here is a SQL statement in MySQL log:

`INSERT INTO tracking_data (`id`,` route`,` data`,` user_id`,` created_at`,` updated_at`,` modify_date`) VALUES (5, 'route1', _binary'��\0t\0{\"route\": \"value\"}', 1, null, null, '2022-05-05 06:21:59')`

And here is an example of my Nifi flow:

[Nifi example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlWSX.png)

Could you please let me know why Nifi auto-converts the value of JSON column into Binary? And would be best if there are any solutions to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you using ConvertJSONToSQL processor with PutSQL processor? I prefer to use the PutDatabaseRecord processor with JsonTreeReader.

Comment: Thanks @tonykoval, I'll try that way to see that can solve this problem. But do you know how Nifi try to append to the value of JSON column with _binary